# Recommend books for complex analysis for qualifying exam

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am currently preparing qualifying exam for pure  mathematics, and I am looking for books of complex analysis. I found the *Real Analysis* written by G.B.Folland is really helpful, concise and instructive when I learning real analysis. So I really want to find a textbook of complex analysis written like the style of Folland.

I have read some of the books by Alhfors or Stein or Lang or Conway, but none of these fits me very well. For example, the Cauchy Integration theorem in the books of Stein is written into many versions, from weakto strong, which is really terrible for me to have a systemic review. Rudin is old-fashioned and I don't like his style.

Any recommendition is appreciated!

Comment: I don't know if it will suit you but I recommend the Theory of Complex Functions by Remmert and Classical Topics in Complex Function Theory by the same author. If you read French, the Analyse complexe by Amar and Matheron is a chef-d'oeuvre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No doubt in *strongly* suggesting you [this lecture notes](https://www.math.unipd.it/%7Epietro/doc/Complex_Analysis/De%20Marco%20-%20BasicComplexAnalysis.pdf) as an introductory course.

If you want to go further, read [these other notes](https://www.math.unipd.it/%7Epietro/doc/Complex_Analysis/De%20Marco%20-%20Selected%20topics%20of%20Complex%20Analysis2012.pdf).

I find both of them absolutely clear.

Comment: Wow, that's really concise and clear! Thanks you!

Comment: You are welcome! The second notes are inspired by Remmert's book